# Why does calling insertRowsAtIndexPaths: call heightForRow for all rows?

Tags: iphone, ios, cocoa-touch, uitableview, uikit

`heightForRowAtIndexPath` is a very expensive operation when you have a lot of cells. In my case, I have thousands, so I thought I might break the table down in batches and display only 50 cells a time, and as the user nears the end of the table view bounds, use `insertRowsAtIndexPaths:` to insert 50 more rows. However, everytime I insert 50 new rows, `heightForRowAtIndexPath` is called for all rows of the table, not just the ones I just inserted. Is this expected behavior? Why is this? My height for row has to calculate the height of a string with a font, so for it to calculate heights for the entire table every time I insert new rows is extremely ineffiecient. Are there any workarounds?

Answer (score 2):

> Is this expected behavior? Why is this?

Yes, this makes it possible to insert rows with different heights into one table.

> Are there any workarounds?

Calculate the height only once during initialization in case all rows have equal heights.
Every time `heightForRowAtIndexPath` is called, simply return the cached result.

Answer (score 2):

I agree with @Anne.  It needs to be called because a row's position in the table (which is just a scroll view) is established by the position and height of the rows above it.

And @Anne's prescription is pretty much right, too, which boils down to making the height method run as fast as it can.

But the real question is for you. I think the "performance" question you should be asking is about human performance, thumbing through 1000's of rows.

Let's say one flick of the thumb can scroll 10 rows and be performed in a second.  That's 1.5 minutes per thousand.  A million users using your app to scroll 5000 rows once per day would consume 1.9 million workdays each year, reducing national GDP proportionally.

I wish you the utmost success, but please consider the precarious state of the global economy before distributing an app with 1000s of UITableView rows.

Comment: Well how else would I do it? It's like Twitter, or Facebook, you can just keep scrolling and scrolling. What's a better way?

Comment: Two alternatives: (1) Have the last row in your section be a button for "Load more rows..." where you load them lazily based on the user action (2) Implement a search with the above functionality.  The users' need to see all of the possible rows is mitigated by their ability to search specifically for what they are looking for.